# jQuery differences in append(string/ref_jquery_obj/jquery_obj)

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are all ways to append a div to the body of the HTML. But what are the differences and when should I use which (performance-wise).

```
var div = '<div id="divid"></div>';
$('body').append(div);
```

and

```
var div = $('<div id="divid"></div>');
$('body').append(div);
```

and

```
$div = $('<div id="divid"></div>');
$('body').append($div);
```

Comment: That question only contains first 2.. I would like to know the difference between the 3 and when I should use them :)

Comment: 2nd and 3rd are virtually the same, both of them are caching the selectors to be used later..

Comment: @Sushanth-- ah okay :) but which of the 2 would be fastest or the difference will never be noticeable?

Comment: The 1st would be the faster than the other 2 , as you do not have the overhead of creating a jQuery object

Comment: The only difference between 2 and 3 is that the variable `div` is local, while the variable `$div` is potentially global. The `$` has no significance in a variable name.

Comment: This question is more about JavaScript basics than jQuery.  **#2** creates a local variable.  **#3** creates a global variable. Other than that there is no difference between **#2** and **#3**.  The fact that the variable name begins with a `$` in **#3** is just a naming convention for jQuery objects (that is not followed in **#2**).  The main difference between the three is that **#1** appends _text_ to the DOM whereas **#2** and **#3** append _jQuery objects_ to the DOM.  You should use **#2** when you want to manipulate the new div as a jQuery object.  You shouldn't use **#3** (in general).

Comment: @jahroy Thanks or the answer :) but why i should not use 3? If I want to make it a global jquery object why not?

Comment: You can use it if you _actually_ want a global variable... But _in general_ you should not.  Most people consider global objects to be pure evil.  However, there are rare situations when you **HAVE** to use one, so I added the disclaimer "_(in general)_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var div = '<div id="divid"></div>';
$('body').append(div);
```

The above code will work fine when you just want to append html string to the DOM

The below code will work fine when you just want to append jQuery Object to the DOM and you can manipulate it with jQuery

```
var div = $('<div id="divid"></div>');
div.css({//your css code});//this is not possible in above example
$('body').append(div);
```

Comment: How are the 2 different... ?

Comment: But... in the second example, shouldn't it just be `$('#divid')`? How can you include the div itself as a selector. I have never seen `$('<div id="divid"></div>')`

Comment: `$('#divid')` only works , if that div is already present in the DOM.. But the OP wants to create the element and then append it

Comment: @Sushanth
You can check various examples here:-
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: So are you saying `$('<div id="divid"></div>')` will create the div object, but not place it in the DOM until you append? I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: Right, it will be in the memory, but will not be appended to the `DOM` . So you do jQuery manipulations to it by chaining since it is a jQuery object

Comment: Wow...  I don't know what I would use that for, but that's a open door I didn't know existed.

Comment: @Leeish it's useful if you want to append multiple elements. It is faster to build a collection of elements outside the document, and append them all at once, than it is to append them one by one as you create them.

Comment: @Leeish - I've used it before to extract a color from a css style.  **1.** Create a temporary div **2.** apply the style **3.** use _jQuery.css()_ to extract the color.  I never found a better way to do it (though I'm sure one exists)...